# Can I change a "source trees" entry dynamically in xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.6

I have a single project (A) that is used by projects (B) and (C).  In Xcode->preferences->locations I have a setting called PROJECT_SRC that project A references and when I'm working on B.xcodeproj it is set to B's source path.  If I want to work on C.xcodeproj I have to **manually change** the setting to point to C's source.  Is there a way to dynamically alter this setting?

Thanks in advance!
Chris

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using the Locations?   This can probably done just by including a reference to the A project from within the B and C projects.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the other way around and it's not something I can change(not my projects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think what I'm going to need to do is use the System Events plist editing functionality.  I can do this through apple script(mine won't be exactly like this, but you get the point):

```
tell application "System Events"
    set plistFile to property list file "/path/to/file.plist"
    tell plistFile
        tell property list item "array name"
            set value of property list item "x" to "..."
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

I found this in the apple forums [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3236539?start=0&tstart=0)

the plist you need to edit to change the source paths is found in Users/userName/Preferences/come.apple.dt.Xcode.plist